# Не удаётся десереализировать полученный обьект в сервлете в целую строку

Tags: javascript, java, json, java-ee, serialize

Хотел узнать что я делаю не так.. Не силён в сериализации.. Не выводится полная строка JSON, выводится только до Field! При передачи с JS кода видно что передаётся всё.. Значит теряются гдето байты ? Кто сможет направить с использованием Java.IO буду благодарен.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/ContactUs")
public class ContactUs extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = inputStream.toString().getBytes();
    int number = inputStream.read(bytes);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(number);
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytes,0,number);

    System.out.println("Converted to string: "+byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
    System.out.println("The size of byte array: "+byteArrayOutputStream.size());
    System.out.println("Number of bytes was readed: "+number);
```

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {

    var contactInfo = {

        email:$("[name=emailField]").val(),
        userName:$("[name=userName]").val(),
        field:$("[name=field]").val()
    }


    console.log(contactInfo);

    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(contactInfo);
    console.log(JSONString);

    $.ajax({

        url:"http://localhost:9090/Demo/ContactUs",
        method:"post",
        data:JSONString,
        contentType:"application/json",
        error:function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```
[![Вывод в консоле IDEA : 

Converted to string: {"email":"Ludmila@gmail.com","userName":"Ludmila","field
The size of byte array: 56
Number of bytes was readed: 56]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка со сканером :

```
 ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream);
    String data = s.next();

    System.out.println("Scanner: "+data);

Вывод: 

Scanner:   {"email":"Ludmila@gmail.com","userName":"Ludmila","field":"Hello!

Scanner: {"email":"Aleksander@gmail.com","userName":"Aleksandrovich","field":"Hello!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий вариант:

```
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new  StringBuilder(request.toString().length());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    String body = stringBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println("Scanner: " + body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша попытка со сканером неполная, так попробуйте:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) 
               throws ServletException, IOException {        

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(1000);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }    
    String body = stringBuilder.toString();    
    System.out.println("Scanner: " + body);       

}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Выручил!